# Quickblox dialog box - Users not able to recover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, quickblox

I am using the Quickblox new update from [here](http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample) and used [this example](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk/archive/master.zip)

I can see many users are there in the left side panel and users can are loaded when i click **Create Dialog** button.

https://api.quickblox.com/chat/Dialog.json?token=xxyyyzzz

In the above call i can't able to retrieve any users..

What should i do to get users in the left side panel and also in the Dialog popup ?

I can see that when i click on the crate dialog and click on the user i am always getting this response even the `occupant_id` is correct

My request is like this

```
https://api.quickblox.com/chat/Dialog.json
```

and response is always like this even when the occupant_id is correct..

```
{"errors":["Incorrect occupant_id."]}
```

Comment: Could you please specify your issue in more detail? Please have a look at our Documentation, it should be helpful for you: http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Update_dialog

Answer (score -1):

Seems you are trying to create private group. In this case you are trying to put your userID to occupants_id that is 
incorrect.

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/issues/300